# Vim PC window resize/max on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, vim, maximize

I cant figure out why, but my vim74 on Windows 8 wont maximize. In fact it is very limited to a certain size.

[image]

This is the max size and I don't know how to make it bigger.

Also when I input a command (e.g. `:q`) character that I didn't input comes up
like `:<-[1 q` when I do `:q`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot (and missing menus), it looks like you're using Vim in the Windows console (`cmd.exe`), which cannot be maximized in the usual way. You have the following options:

- Use GVIM; it offers more (visual) features, and the biggest disadvantage, more clumsy shell integration, isn't that important on Windows, anyway.
- Use the Windows console menu (right mouse button on the top-left icon > Defaults > /Layout\ > Windows Size) to resize it.
- Inside Vim, you can influence the size via

```
:set lines=40 columns=120
```

and the console will resize accordingly.